# Como utilizar un Cursor en SQL Server Para agrupar y leer los resultados de un ciclo while

Tags: sql, sql-server, transact-sql

Tengo una consulta que utiliza un ciclo while para arrojarme un top 10 de clientes con mas solicitudes por cada mes.

```
use 
[GSEControl]
go


DECLARE @i INT, @mes int;


SET @i =1
SET @mes = 12
    


 
WHILE @i <= @mes 
        BEGIN  (
            SELECT TOP (10) 
                            ROW_NUMBER () OVER (order by count(distinct CE.ContratoEjecucionId) desc)  as Posicion,
                            'CONSULTA: Solicitadas' as Identificador, 
                            count(distinct CE.ContratoEjecucionId )   Recuento,
                            case   DATEPART(MONTH, CCE.fechahora )
                                when 1 then 'Enero' 
                                when 2 then 'Febrero' 
                                when 3 then 'Marzo' 
                                when 4 then 'Abril' 
                                when 5 then 'Mayo' 
                                when 6 then 'Junio' 
                                when 7 then 'Julio' 
                                when 8 then 'Agosto' 
                                when 9 then 'Septiembre' 
                                when 10 then 'Octubre' 
                                when 11 then 'Noviembre' 
                                when 12 then 'Diciembre' 
                                end as Mes_Transacción,

                            --cliente

                            case 
                                when C.Tipo='C' then 'Convenio' 
                                when C.Tipo='V' then 'Venta Call'
                                when C.Tipo='K' then 'VinKel'
                                when C.Tipo='P' then 'PT - Facturación electrónica'
                                when C.Tipo='D' and C.SuperContratoId=1 then 'DIAN'
                                when C.Tipo='D' and C.SuperContratoId=3 then 'Colfactura' 
                                else 'Otro tipo' end as Tipo,
                            CL.TipoIdentificacionId  as cliente_tipoid,
                            CL.TerceroId  as cliente_identificacion,
                            ltrim(upper(coalesce(CL.RazonSocial,concat(CL.PrimerApellido, coalesce(' ' + CL.SegundoApellido + ' ', ' '),CL.PrimerNombre, coalesce(' ' + CL.SegundoNombre, ''))))) as cliente_nombre,

                            -- SERVICIO CONTRATADO

                            TC.Nombre as tipo_certificado, 
                            TD.Nombre as tipo_emision

            from 
                ContratoEjecucion as CE with(nolock)
                left join ContratoServicio CS with(nolock) on ( CS.ContratoServicioId = CE.ContratoServicioId )
                left join Contrato C with(nolock) on ( C.ContratoId = CS.ContratoId )
                left join TipoCertificado TC with(nolock) on ( TC.TipoServicioId = CS.TipoServicioId and  TC.TipoCertificadoId = CS.TipoCertificadoId )
                left join TipoDispositivo TD with(nolock) on ( TD.TipoDispositivoId = CS.TipoDispositivoId )
                left join Tercero CL with(nolock) on ( CL.TerceroId = C.Cliente )
                left join Tercero SU with(nolock) on ( CE.Suscriptor = SU.TerceroId )
                left join EstadoServicio ES with(nolock) on ( ES.EstadoServicioId = CE.EstadoServicioId )
                left join Certificado CR with(nolock) on ( CR.ContratoEjecucionId   = CE.ContratoEjecucionId )
                left join ContratoEjecucionEstado CCE with(nolock) on (CE.ContratoEjecucionId=CCE.contratoejecucionid)
                left join UsuarioDatoAdicional UDA with(nolock) on (UDA.UserId = CCE.Gestor)

            where DATEPART(MONTH, CCE.fechahora ) = @i

            group by 
                    CL.TerceroId,
                    C.Tipo,
                    C.SuperContratoId,
                    CL.TipoIdentificacionId,
                    ltrim(upper(coalesce(CL.RazonSocial,concat(CL.PrimerApellido, coalesce(' ' + CL.SegundoApellido + ' ', ' '),CL.PrimerNombre, coalesce(' ' + CL.SegundoNombre, ''))))),
                    TC.Nombre, 
                    TD.Nombre,
                    DATEPART(MONTH, CCE.fechahora )

                    )

                set @i = @i + 1;
        END;
```

Pero necesito que las tablas que me arroja la consulta esten agrupados en una sola:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para esto leei varios foros y termine por decantarme a usar un CURSOR

```
use 
[GSEControl]
go

DECLARE @Resultados as TABLE (Posicion BIGINT,Identificador text, Recuento INT,Mes_Transacción INT, Tipo text, cliente_tipoid text, cliente_identificacion int, cliente_nombre text, tipo_certificado text,tipo_emision  text);

DECLARE Product_Cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM @Resultados;

DECLARE @i INT, @mes int;


SET @i =1
SET @mes = 12
    
OPEN Product_Cursor; 
FETCH NEXT FROM Product_Cursor;

 
WHILE @i <= @mes and @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN insert into @Resultados (
            SELECT TOP (10) 
                            ROW_NUMBER () OVER (order by count(distinct CE.ContratoEjecucionId) desc)  as Posicion,
                            'CONSULTA: Solicitadas' as Identificador, 
                            count(distinct CE.ContratoEjecucionId )   Recuento,
                            case   DATEPART(MONTH, CCE.fechahora )
                                when 1 then 'Enero' 
                                when 2 then 'Febrero' 
                                when 3 then 'Marzo' 
                                when 4 then 'Abril' 
                                when 5 then 'Mayo' 
                                when 6 then 'Junio' 
                                when 7 then 'Julio' 
                                when 8 then 'Agosto' 
                                when 9 then 'Septiembre' 
                                when 10 then 'Octubre' 
                                when 11 then 'Noviembre' 
                                when 12 then 'Diciembre' 
                                end as Mes_Transacción,

                            --cliente

                            case 
                                when C.Tipo='C' then 'Convenio' 
                                when C.Tipo='V' then 'Venta Call'
                                when C.Tipo='K' then 'VinKel'
                                when C.Tipo='P' then 'PT - Facturación electrónica'
                                when C.Tipo='D' and C.SuperContratoId=1 then 'DIAN'
                                when C.Tipo='D' and C.SuperContratoId=3 then 'Colfactura' 
                                else 'Otro tipo' end as Tipo,
                            CL.TipoIdentificacionId  as cliente_tipoid,
                            CL.TerceroId  as cliente_identificacion,
                            ltrim(upper(coalesce(CL.RazonSocial,concat(CL.PrimerApellido, coalesce(' ' + CL.SegundoApellido + ' ', ' '),CL.PrimerNombre, coalesce(' ' + CL.SegundoNombre, ''))))) as cliente_nombre,

                            -- SERVICIO CONTRATADO

                            TC.Nombre as tipo_certificado, 
                            TD.Nombre as tipo_emision



            from 
                ContratoEjecucion as CE with(nolock)
                left join ContratoServicio CS with(nolock) on ( CS.ContratoServicioId = CE.ContratoServicioId )
                left join Contrato C with(nolock) on ( C.ContratoId = CS.ContratoId )
                left join TipoCertificado TC with(nolock) on ( TC.TipoServicioId = CS.TipoServicioId and  TC.TipoCertificadoId = CS.TipoCertificadoId )
                left join TipoDispositivo TD with(nolock) on ( TD.TipoDispositivoId = CS.TipoDispositivoId )
                left join Tercero CL with(nolock) on ( CL.TerceroId = C.Cliente )
                left join Tercero SU with(nolock) on ( CE.Suscriptor = SU.TerceroId )
                left join EstadoServicio ES with(nolock) on ( ES.EstadoServicioId = CE.EstadoServicioId )
                left join Certificado CR with(nolock) on ( CR.ContratoEjecucionId   = CE.ContratoEjecucionId )
                left join ContratoEjecucionEstado CCE with(nolock) on (CE.ContratoEjecucionId=CCE.contratoejecucionid)
                left join UsuarioDatoAdicional UDA with(nolock) on (UDA.UserId = CCE.Gestor)

            where DATEPART(MONTH, CCE.fechahora ) = @i

            group by 
                    CL.TerceroId,
                    C.Tipo,
                    C.SuperContratoId,
                    CL.TipoIdentificacionId,
                    ltrim(upper(coalesce(CL.RazonSocial,concat(CL.PrimerApellido, coalesce(' ' + CL.SegundoApellido + ' ', ' '),CL.PrimerNombre, coalesce(' ' + CL.SegundoNombre, ''))))),
                    TC.Nombre, 
                    TD.Nombre,
                    DATEPART(MONTH, CCE.fechahora )

                    )

                set @i = @i + 1;
FETCH NEXT FROM Product_Cursor;
        END;
CLOSE Product_Cursor; 
DEALLOCATE Product_Cursor;
```

pero obtengo un error "Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 21
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 86
Incorrect syntax near ')'."

Tambien intete cambiando la linea 20 por`BEGIN set @Resultados = (`
pero obtengo el error:
"Msg 137, Level 16, State 1, Line 20
Must declare the scalar variable "@Resultados"."

Si alguien me puede explicar por favor donde estoy aplicando mal el CURSOR o donde esta la falla en la lógica de esta consulta seria de mucha ayuda.

Comment: ufff...realmente ni el cursor ni el while son necesarios. De hecho, solo hacen que tu consulta sea más lenta

Comment: Por otro lado, tu condición es solo por mes, cuando debería incluir también el año...sino por ejemplo puedes comparar clientes de enero de este año con los del 2021

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno el escenario es un poco "caos" pero obviando el hecho de que los cursores y bucles, no son muy bien recibidos por los programadores de lenguajes de base de datos tipo `TSQL`. Esto queda para otra conversación.

Una solución simple.

```
-- ESTO ES LO MISMO QUE WITH (NOLOCK)
-- Revisar: https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
--
DECLARE @VARTABLE TABLE
(
myId int identity(1,1), --esta columna es especial.
Posicion tinyint, 
Identificador varchar(50),
Recuento int,
Mes_Transacción varchar(20),
Tipo varchar(30),
cliente_tipoid varchar(20),
cliente_identificacion varchar(10),
cliente_nombre nvarchar(200),
tipo_certificado varchar(200),
tipo_emision varchar(100)
);
-- las columnas de @varTable tienen que ser del mismo tipo y del
-- tamaño suficiente, de lo que hasta ahora recogías en la select del while.

DECLARE @I   INT
      , @Mes int;

SET @I = 1;

SET @Mes = 12;

WHILE @I <= @Mes
BEGIN
    Insert into @VARTABLE (-- no va la columna especial
        Posicion, Identificador, Recuento,
        Mes_Transacción, Tipo, cliente_tipoid,
        cliente_identificacion, cliente_nombre,
        tipo_certificado,tipo_emision
        ) -- identifico todas las columnas que llenaré con la select
      SELECT TOP (10) Row_Number() OVER(
                      order by Count(distinct CE.ContratoEjecucionId) desc) as Posicion
                    , 'CONSULTA: Solicitadas' as Identificador
                    , Count(distinct CE.ContratoEjecucionId) AS Recuento
                    , case DatePart(MONTH, CCE.fechahora)
                          when 1 then 'Enero'
                          when 2 then 'Febrero'
                          when 3 then 'Marzo'
                          when 4 then 'Abril'
                          when 5 then 'Mayo'
                          when 6 then 'Junio'
                          when 7 then 'Julio'
                          when 8 then 'Agosto'
                          when 9 then 'Septiembre'
                          when 10 then 'Octubre'
                          when 11 then 'Noviembre'
                          when 12 then 'Diciembre'
                      end as Mes_Transacción

                      --cliente
                    , case
                          when C.Tipo = 'C' then 'Convenio'
                          when C.Tipo = 'V' then 'Venta Call'
                          when C.Tipo = 'K' then 'VinKel'
                          when C.Tipo = 'P' then 'PT - Facturación electrónica'
                          when C.Tipo = 'D' and C.SuperContratoId = 1 then 'DIAN'
                          when C.Tipo = 'D' and C.SuperContratoId = 3 then 'Colfactura'
                      else 'Otro tipo'
                      end as Tipo
                    , CL.TipoIdentificacionId as cliente_tipoid
                    , CL.TerceroId as cliente_identificacion
                    , Ltrim(Upper(Coalesce(CL.RazonSocial, concat(CL.PrimerApellido, Coalesce(' ' + CL.SegundoApellido + ' ', ' '), CL.PrimerNombre, Coalesce(' ' + CL.SegundoNombre, ''))))) as cliente_nombre

                      -- SERVICIO CONTRATADO
                    , TC.Nombre as tipo_certificado
                    , TD.Nombre as tipo_emision
             from ContratoEjecucion as CE 
                  left join ContratoServicio AS CS  on CS.ContratoServicioId = CE.ContratoServicioId
                  left join Contrato AS C  on C.ContratoId = CS.ContratoId
                  left join TipoCertificado AS TC  on TC.TipoServicioId = CS.TipoServicioId and TC.TipoCertificadoId = CS.TipoCertificadoId
                  left join TipoDispositivo AS TD  on TD.TipoDispositivoId = CS.TipoDispositivoId
                  left join Tercero AS CL  on CL.TerceroId = C.Cliente
                  left join Tercero AS SU  on CE.Suscriptor = SU.TerceroId
                  left join EstadoServicio AS ES  on ES.EstadoServicioId = CE.EstadoServicioId
                  left join Certificado AS CR  on CR.ContratoEjecucionId = CE.ContratoEjecucionId
                  left join ContratoEjecucionEstado AS CCE  on CE.ContratoEjecucionId = CCE.contratoejecucionid
                  left join UsuarioDatoAdicional AS UDA  on UDA.UserId = CCE.Gestor
             where DatePart(MONTH, CCE.fechahora) = @I
             group by CL.TerceroId
                    , C.Tipo
                    , C.SuperContratoId
                    , CL.TipoIdentificacionId
                    , Ltrim(Upper(Coalesce(CL.RazonSocial, concat(CL.PrimerApellido, Coalesce(' ' + CL.SegundoApellido + ' ', ' '), CL.PrimerNombre, Coalesce(' ' + CL.SegundoNombre, '')))))
                    , TC.Nombre
                    , TD.Nombre
                    , DatePart(MONTH, CCE.fechahora)
    
    set @I = @I + 1;
END;

-- En la variable tipo tabla tengo todo el contenido.

Select 
    * from @VARTABLE t;

-- la columna especial me numera incrementalmente cada una de las insert.
```

En resumidas cuentas. Declaramos una variable tipo `Table`, que contendrá toda la información de cada una de las consultas. En cada iteración del bucle while, le insertamos lo que tiene cada select.

Cuando ha terminado el bucle while, le damos salida a la información de la variable de tipo `Table`

Comment: Muchas gracias,  me funciona a la perfección tendré en cuenta para futuras consultas el ``SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;`` y también por la aclaración del identity(1,1) al momento de declarar tablas como variables.